# Backbone with non-Restful services

Tags: rest, backbone.js

I am looking at backbone for a project. I have many legacy services which are non-restful that I have no choice but to use them as is. I see that I have to override Backbone.Model.sync, parse and many other methods and handle the ajax service calls. I am not sure how the routing is going to work but I can see that there will be a lot of extra code to make that work. My question is: Is Backbone really recommended if I have to work with non-restful services? I don't find any examples or discussion anywhere online which talks about it.

Comment: Overriding `parse` has nothing to do with whether the API follows the REST convention. And `sync` is more "low-level" than changes in the URL schema. All you'll have to do is stop using the `root` attribute of collections to generate model URLs and assign custom URLs to your models using a custom function... See [model.url in the docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Backbone's automatic understanding of REST conventions boils down to probably about 50 lines of code. If your back-end APIs are all odd and unique, yes, you'll need to write code to talk to them, but you'll need that no matter which framework you use because no framework is going to understand the unique weirdnesses of your back end services. If you feel good about the basic MVC with event bindings design of backbone, stick with it. That's the core of it. And it's a tiny core, that's why it's called backbone.

As per routing, that's really handled in the browser as a single page app and the browser URL routing and associated backbone router/view code is entirely separate from the API patterns and URLs that provide the back end services. The two can be utterly unrelated and that's fine. You'll still be able to define your own browser routing however you see fit.